# Use index, match, and row/column excel functions in a formula to return a subset array with just cells with text and exclude the empty ones

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match, formula

I have this scenario where i want to extract a subset of a range in one row (using index, match and row functions preferably )  and return only smaller filtered array with cells that contain text/data and exclude empty cells .. I want to use this filtered array for further processing

The input 2-D array i want to get a subset array from is colored

[The image shows the returned array size in last column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v37KD.png)

A dropdown menu is provided for the user to select the desired row (say A1:A6).

The row selected by the user determines which row of the 2-D colored range (say B1:G6 ) to extract the filtered array from
then only cells with text/data are returned from that row

I tried the following code

I can get the array of whole correct row (all cells) using

```
index(B1:G6, match(A1:A6,value_from_dropdown_menue,0),0)
```

then i tried to apply row() function to filter out empty elements from that returned array .. lets refer to the **returned_full_row_array** as **RFRA** for readability

```
index(RFRA, row(indirect("1:"& counta(RFRA))))
```

the full formula looks like this (**B8** is the cell with dropdown )

```
=INDEX(INDEX(2D_Matrix,MATCH(B8,1D_Menue_List,0),0),ROW(indirect("1:"& counta(INDEX(2D_Matrix,MATCH(B8,1D_Menue_List,0),0)))))
```

but the row() function is not returning an array and thus i don't any array returned .. i only get the first element.. even if i hardcoded row(1:3) .. i don't get 3 element array back ... only the first element of the the whole row

any ideas?

Edit : I can successfully get the whole row of my range using index match
the result is a fixed size 1 by 6 array like this (example first and 2nd row ):

```
for 1st row >> {"M1-item1",0,0,0,0,0}
for 2nd row >> {"M2-item1","M2-item2","M2-item3","M2-item4",0,0}
```

desired output however should be a **variable length array** without the empty/zero elements :

```
for 1st row >> {"M1-item1"}
for 2nd row >> {"M2-item1","M2-item2","M2-item3","M2-item4"}
```

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Hi Scott, I am using excel 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the original question has changed, this is a much simpler problem. Let's say that we have some named ranges:

| Named Range | Formula | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `FullRange` | `=L15:Q22` | The full range of the data |
| `MenuList` | `=K15:K22` | The list of menu items |
| `DropdownSelection` | ? | The cell with the dropdown list |

This would be the formula to do the job:

```
=INDEX(
    FullRange,
    XMATCH(DropdownSelection,MenuList,0),
    XMATCH(
        SEQUENCE(
            ,
            MAX(
                MMULT(
                    SEQUENCE(,ROWS(FullRange),1,0),
                    MMULT((1-ISBLANK(FullRange))*(DropdownSelection=MenuList),
                    (SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(FullRange))<=SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(FullRange)))*1)
                )
            )
        ),
        MMULT(
            SEQUENCE(,ROWS(FullRange),1,0),
            MMULT(
                (1-ISBLANK(FullRange))*(DropdownSelection=MenuList),
                (SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(FullRange))<=SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(FullRange)))*1
            )
        ),
        0
    )
)
```

Sorry it's so ugly in the middle. It uses `ISBLANK` to find which cells are used.

In particular, this part:

```
SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(FullRange))<=SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(FullRange)))*1
```

produces an upper triangular matrix.

If we have a matrix that contains this:

```
(1-ISBLANK(FullRange))*(DropdownSelection=MenuList)
```

it will contain only those cells we actually want.

By taking the matrix product, we get a matrix with 0's everywhere except on the row we're after. On the row we're after, it has 1 on the first cell we want up to the 2nd cell, 2 on the second cell we want up to the third, and so on. By `XMATCH`ing from the left (going right), it will only match on those cells we want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic, painful problem. I like to solve it by firstly moving all the elements in the range into a single column, like this:

```
=LET(
     InputArray,
     B1:G8,
     InputRowCount,
     ROWS(InputArray),
     TotalCellCount,
     COLUMNS(InputArray)*InputRowCount,
     LookupRow,
     MOD(SEQUENCE(TotalCellCount,,0),InputRowCount),
     LookupColumn,
     (SEQUENCE(TotalCellCount,,0)-LookupRow)/InputRowCount,
     RearrangedAsColumn,
     INDEX(InputArray,LookupRow,LookupColumn),
     RearrangedAsColumn_IsBlank,
     INDEX(ISBLANK(InputArray),LookupRow,LookupColumn),
     Result,
     FILTER(RearrangedAsColumn,1-RearrangedAsColumn_IsBlank),
     Result
)
```

I used a LET function here, because it allows me to define variables, and makes the explanation a little clearer.

Stepping through:

| Name | What it does |
| --- | --- |
| `InputArray` | That's where the data comes from |
| `InputRows` | Count up the rows |
| `InputColumns` | Count up the columns |
| `LookupRow` | This uses division remainders to give us the row references |
| `LookupColumn` | This calculates our column lookup |
| `RearrangedAsColumn` | This restates InputArray into a single column |
| `RearrangedAsColumn_IsBlank` | Gives us a column that shows whether or not the cell is blank |
| `Result` | Finally, filter RearrangedAsColumn for non-blank cells |

I hope this is what you're after!

Comment: Thanks Justin, but unfortunately i cannot make use of the **let** function as I am using Excel 2013.  Thats why i mentioned i prefer index match + row or column

Comment: No problem. It's messier, but you can substitute the variable formulas in place of the variable names when solving. This would give a formula like this: ```=FILTER(INDEX(B1:G8,MOD(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B1:G8)*ROWS(B1:G8),,0),ROWS(B1:G8)),(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B1:G8)*ROWS(B1:G8),,0)-MOD(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B1:G8)*ROWS(B1:G8),,0),ROWS(B1:G8)))/ROWS(B1:G8)),1-INDEX(ISBLANK(B1:G8),MOD(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B1:G8)*ROWS(B1:G8),,0),ROWS(B1:G8)),(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B1:G8)*ROWS(B1:G8),,0)-MOD(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B1:G8)*ROWS(B1:G8),,0),ROWS(B1:G8)))/ROWS(B1:G8)))```

Comment: Alternatively, if you're happy to hard code the row and column counts, you would get a formula like this: ```=FILTER(INDEX(B1:G8,MOD(SEQUENCE(48,,0),8),(SEQUENCE(48,,0)-MOD(SEQUENCE(48,,0),8))/8),1-INDEX(ISBLANK(B1:G8),MOD(SEQUENCE(48,,0),8),(SEQUENCE(48,,0)-MOD(SEQUENCE(48,,0),8))/8))```